# RestTemplate handle [image/jpg] response content type in java

Tags: java, spring, tapestry

Sorry, i am newbie on java web development.

I got some task to fetch user profile picture from 3rd party company via HTTP rest(GET method). Their api only can be accessed using session id on the header parameter and the api will return some byte[] array looks like `’ÑÒBRSb¢ÂáTr²ñ#‚4“â3C` etc.

**How to handle rest response with content type image/jpg in Rest Template?**

I do my best like this

```
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

public byte[] getProfilePic(){
  String canonicalPath = "http://dockertest/bankingapp/customer/profpicFile";
  String sessionId= "MTQ4NzE5Mz...etc";

  HttpEntity<byte[]> request = new HttpEntity<byte[]>(null, getHeaders(true, "GET", null, canonicalPath, sessionId));
  //getHeaders() will return HttpHeaders with those parameter

  ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = null;
  try {
    response = this.restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, request, byte[].class);
  } catch( HttpServerErrorException hse ){
    throw hse;
  }
  return response;
}
```

This code will return an error

> org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract
>   response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type
>   [[B] and content type [image/jpg]

Any suggestion or help will be appreciated!

Thank you

**Update**

Using stackoveflower suggestions i can manage to solve this.

```
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

public byte[] getProfilePic(){
  String canonicalPath = "/mobile/customer/profpicFile";
  String sessionId= "MTQ4NzE5Mz...etc";

  HttpEntity<byte[]> request = new HttpEntity<byte[]>(null, getHeaders(true, "GET", null, canonicalPath, sessionId));
  //getHeaders() will return HttpHeaders with those parameter

  ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = null;
  try {
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
    response = this.restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, request, byte[].class).getBody();
    return response;
  } catch( HttpServerErrorException hse ){
    throw hse;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Note about HttpMessageConverter, instead using list, i can directly add a `ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter()`

Comment: you should use the right converter. More info can be found here https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#setMessageConverters-java.util.List- I guess you should add the https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said I guess you must use the right `messageconverter` 
I would do in this way:

```
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

public byte[] getProfilePic(){
  String canonicalPath = "http://dockertest/bankingapp/customer/profpicFile";
  String sessionId= "MTQ4NzE5Mz...etc";
  List<HttpMessageConverter> converters = new ArrayList<>(1);
  converters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
  restTemplate.setMessageConverters(converters);
  HttpEntity<byte[]> request = new HttpEntity<byte[]>(null, getHeaders(true, "GET", null, canonicalPath, sessionId));
  //getHeaders() will return HttpHeaders with those parameter

  ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = null;
  try {
    response = this.restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, request, byte[].class);
  } catch( HttpServerErrorException hse ){
    throw hse;
  }
  return response;
}
```

More information can be found here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#setMessageConverters-java.util.List- and here https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html and here https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter.html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much,this problem takes up my a lot of time. Now,it was resolved.
following:

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class RestTemplateConfiguration implements ApplicationContextAware {

@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = (RestTemplate) applicationContext.getBean("restTemplate");
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
    restTemplate.setUriTemplateHandler(new GetUriTemplateHandler());
}
```

}